# Java JTable not showing the records

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hive

I am trying to get the records from Hive into JTable in a new frame.The new frame pops up with Column names but the records are not visible.Here is my code.

```
try{
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet res;
   stmt.setMaxRows(val);
   sql = "select * from default.recommendations where recommendations.item='" + user +"'";
   System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
   res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   while (res.next()) {
   System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2) + "\t" + res.getString(3));
   }                        
   ResultSetMetaData rsmt = res.getMetaData();
   int c = rsmt.getColumnCount();
   Vector column = new Vector(c);
   for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
   column.add(rsmt.getColumnName(i));
   }
   Vector data = new Vector();
   Vector row = new Vector();
   while (res.next()) {              
   row = new Vector(c);
   for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
   row.add(res.getString(i));
   }
   data.add(row);
   }
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(500, 120);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   JTable table = new JTable(data,column);
   JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
   panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   panel.add(jsp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   frame.setContentPane(panel);
   frame.setVisible(true);
} catch(SQLException se){
System.Out.Println(se.getMessage())}
```

Comment: Separate out the GUI code from the database code so that they can be debugged separately, and then do that -- debug your individual classes separately and **with** a debugger. Find the location of your error. Then if still stuck, come on back with **well formatted code**, not code with terrible formatting as you've posted above (indentations do matter). Best if you post an [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (res.next()) 
{
   System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2) + "\t" + res.getString(3));
}
```

After doing the query you read all the data and display it on the console.

```
while (res.next()) {              
   row = new Vector(c);
   for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
   row.add(res.getString(i));
   }
   data.add(row);
   }
```

Then later you try to read the data into the Vectors. Problem is that there is no data in the ResultSet because you have already read all the data.

Get rid of the first loop.

If you want to see the values of the ResultSet then put the System.out.println(...) statement in the second loop.